# Hiding the path to redirected URL in Node

Tags: node.js, url, redirect, proxy

Good day!

Here's a question... we are storing a large file in the third party storage. The link to it is located on our website built with Express in Node. The goal is to make sure that the client doesn't see the path to the external website.

Examples:

File actual location: http://www.some.storage/bucket/SuperBigFile.exe

Path to file from our website: http://www.ourWeb.site/files/SuperBigFile.exe

I tired it with

```
res.redirect("http://www.some.storage/bucket/SuperBigFile.exe");
```

and

```
request('http://www.some.storage/bucket/SuperBigFile.exe').pipe(res);
```

request(...).pipe(res) would stream the file through our server and the file itself is a pdf report with a size of 300mb. Everything that goes through our primary server usually gets hung after 30-40mb, that was the primary reason of moving the file to the storage, but the client doesn't want the users to see the path to the storage...

Both versions redirect to download the file and it can be in fact accessed through http://www.ourWeb.site/files/SuperBigFile.exe url, but let's say if I'm using fidler debugger, I can see requests to the original file at the storage. Is there a way to hide it completely so, it won't be visible from the client side? So, the client would think that it is coming from our website?

Thanks.

Comment: Your second solution would hide it from the client. What is the problem with that?

Comment: My bad for not clarifying the issue. pipe(res) would stream the file through our server and the file itself is a pdf report with a size of 300mb. Everything that goes through our primary server usually gets hung after 30-40mb. That's why we wanted to use the storage in the first place... but the client doesn't want users to see that we are using external storage, thus, using request().pipe(res) is sort of not a solution.

Comment: If that's the case, then you need to "fix" your primary server as there is no other way to do what you want, besides a redirect.

Comment: That's what my research is leading to... Thank.